# When using GHCi Haskell trace, how does one avoid interleaving output?

Tags: haskell, show, trace

While using The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.2, I'm trying to add trace information to the following script:

```
import Debug.Trace
init :: Show a => [a] -> [a]
init l@(x:xs) | trace
          (
            if (length l) < 2
               then ( "\n\tinit [" ++ show x ++ "] = []" )
               else ( "\n\tinit " ++ show l ++ " = " ++ show x ++ " : (init " ++ show xs ++ ")" )
          ) False = undefined
init [_] = []
init (x:xs) = x : (Main.init xs)
```

However, the output of the trace is interleaved with the output of evaluating the expression `Main.init [2,3,5,7]`, as shown below:

```
C:\>ghci my_script.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( my_script.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> Main.init [2,3,5,7]

        init [2,3,5,7] = 2 : (init [3,5,7])
[2
        init [3,5,7] = 3 : (init [5,7])
,3
        init [5,7] = 5 : (init [7])
,5
        init [7] = []
]
*Main> :quit
Leaving GHCi.
```

How would one cause the following four lines to be omitted from the output?

```
[2
,3
,5
]
```

I have already tried using a couple of different variations of `:set -fno-print-bind-result` as shown at https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html, but to no avail.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into questions. If you have something to add to the existing answers, leave a comment to them or, if it is a different solution altogether, post it as a new answer (it is fine to answer your own questions). I have rolled back your edits -- here is [a link to the source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5c2a5320-46d9-4819-9c24-af15f377a533/view-source), in case you want to use them for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the reason those lines are interleaved is because the list is the actual return value of your `Main.init` function. To be able to see the trace you need to force execution of the `Main.init` function. You could do this by enforcing strictness (`seq`, `deepseq`), but I think the simplest way would be to simply use the result in a way that doesn't interleave intermediate results.

If you just want the trace without interleaved data but you don't care about data at the end, how about using `sum` to use the list.

I suggest you try in ghci:

```
λ > sum (Main.init [2,3,5,7])

    init [2,3,5,7] = 2 : (init [3,5,7])

    init [3,5,7] = 3 : (init [5,7])

    init [5,7] = 5 : (init [7])

    init [7] = []
10
```

**Other method**:

Since trace outputs to `stderr` and not `stdout` you can split the output on the command line:

```
➜  ~ ghc temp.hs -e "Main.init [2, 3, 5, 7]" > /dev/null

    init [2,3,5,7] = 2 : (init [3,5,7])

    init [3,5,7] = 3 : (init [5,7])

    init [5,7] = 5 : (init [7])

    init [7] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

GHCi implicitly uses `print`, and being lazy, it prints elements of a list as it evaluates them. You can compose it with a function that forces the whole list first.

```
force :: [a] -> [a]
force xs = go xs `seq` xs
  where go [] = ()
        go (x : xs) = x `seq` go xs
```

In ghci:

```
> print . force $ init [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

---

`force` also exists in a more general form in the deepseq library,
and with it you can use [-interactive-print](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#using-a-custom-interactive-printing-function) to set `print . force` to be the default printer.